# WCF Service hosted in IIS, SQLDependency

Tags: wcf, sqldependency

I have searched on the internet on polling a dabatase every few minutes from a WCF service hosted in IIS and the best answer I could get is to use SQL Depedency. I have found a lot of articles on how to use SQL Dependency but my question is:

If the service has no activity for a long time and a new record is inserted into the table that needs to be polled, will the service be alerted. IIS let the service sleep if there is no activity. Does the SQLDependency wake up the service?

Comment: By this you mean service is running and checking if any new data has come...I would prefer keeping some one at the door of my house to know if a guest is coming rather than entering to the house and checking each minute..

Comment: Well that is why I would rather use the SQL Dependency and hence the question. Will the service be notified when using SQL Dependency if IIS has set the service to sleep. It could be that 2 weeks past without anything happening on the database. If an insert happens after 2 weeks will the service be notified by the SQL Dependency?

Comment: I must add, that I have never used SQLDependency before and only read up on it now. Maybe I am misunderstanding it. Please push me in the right direction if I do misunderstood it.